Cypress failed test screenshot are smaller when running inside docker container, any fix?
I have set my test to viewportWidth: 1920 and viewportHeight: 1080. When running locally, if a test fails, the screenshot captures the entire window.
However, when I run it in Docker (cypress/browser image), the screenshot only captures a part of the screen.
From my research, I understand that the issue arises because there is no X11 server running in the Docker container, and the default screen size is set to 1280x720. Therefore, during the test, the screenshot cannot exceed this assumed screen size.
Source : https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2102
According to Cypress's official documentation, to run tests on Linux, we need an X11 server. They provide the command Xvfb -screen 0 1024x768x24 :99 & to start an instance of the X11 server. I attempted to start the Xvfb server with Xvfb -screen 0 1920x1080x24 :99 and set the DISPLAY=:99 before running the Cypress command, but it did not seem to resolve the issue.
Source : https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/introduction
I also tried using a different port in case there was already an X11 server running with:
/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/Xvfb :98 -screen 1 1920x1080x24 &
and
export DISPLAY=:98 && cypress run ...
However, it did not work.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem?
Best regards,
Search on internet,
Xvfb -screen 0 1024x768x24 :99 & to start the X11 server in combinaison with export DISPLAY=:99
Do the same on an other port
